# How to fix sort in ascending and descending order?

Tags: c#, sorting

I have this error that I cannot get the selection sort into the correct ascending and descending order. I have tried every possible solution to fix this, but I cannot come up with anything else. If anyone would be willing to help me solve this, I would be very appreciated.

**Error Example -**

- Bruce Wayne
- Clark Kent
- Ronald Raymond
- Dinah Lance
- Arthur Curry
- Shayera Hol

**How I want it to be -**

- Arthur Curry
- Bruce Wayne
- Clark Kent
- Dinah Lance
- Ronald Raymond
- Shayera Hol

The sorting method

```
public static void Sort(Employee[] emp, int size, int choice) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size - 1; j++) {
            bool switchval = false;
            switch (choice) {
                case 1: // ascending sort by employee name 
                    if (emp[j].GetName().CompareTo(emp[j + 1].GetName()) > 0)
                        switchval = true;
                    break;
                case 2: // ascending sort by employee number
                    if (emp[j].GetNumber() > emp[j + 1].GetNumber())
                        switchval = true;
                    break;
                case 3: // descending sort by hourly rate
                    if (emp[j].GetRate() < emp[j + 1].GetRate())
                        switchval = true;
                    break;
                case 4: // descending sort by weekly hours
                    if (emp[j].GetHours() < emp[j + 1].GetHours())
                        switchval = true;
                    break;
                case 5: // descending sort by gross pay 
                    if (emp[j].GetGross() < emp[j + 1].GetGross())
                        switchval = true;
                    break;
            }
            if (switchval) { 
                Employee temp;
                temp = emp[i];
                emp[i] = emp[j];
                emp[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in C#7 you can swap the two variables using a tuple: `(emp[i], emp[j]) = (emp[j], emp[i]);`

Comment: Why did you just delete the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64638646/how-to-ignore-line-if-it-already-exists question? It seemed perfectly answerable; I was just waiting on the complete code to make sure it was easy for you to implement.

Comment: @Enigmativity it was impossible to send the complete code as it had a streamreader file with words in scrambles.

Comment: @BeR - That doesn't seem like it would be impossible. You could use postbin in any case. Nonetheless, the answer is simple, but your code was written in a complicated way. I was hoping to show you the answer and how to simplify your coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to implement the `bubble sort` algorithm, but you're iterating over the array incorrectly. First, change the inner for loop to be:

```
for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
```

Then change the if block to be:

```
if (switchval)
{
    Employee temp;
    temp = emp[j];
    emp[j] = emp[j+1];
    emp[j+1] = temp;
}
```

As you want to do this based on `j`, not `i` (as `i` serves to iterate all of the elements, and not part of the sorting itself).

Comment: This WORKED. Thank you so much.

Comment: it's a good answer, but there is some presumption going on in it.  OP didn't actual say there were implementing a 'traditional' bubble sort (`n^2` iterations);  in your answer you made that determination, but I think that is a bit skewed.  `i` can be used in deriving the upper bounds of `j` in the comparison iterations. i.e `for (int j = 0; j < size - 1 - i; j++)`.  this is known as an optimized bubble sort.  you should also be checking in `i` loop whether any swap has occurred throughout the `j` comparison iterations. if not, it's sorted, exit `i` loop. (this behavior is part of bubble sort)

Comment: after thinking about it; I created an answer from my comment here.

Comment: @BrettCaswell It's true that there are optimisations to be performed, but my answer was based on the minimum amount of changes required. If I was to recommend the best course of action, then I would suggest something drastic different

Answer (score 0):

To extend on @Hayden's answer (and on my comment to it): you should replace all references of `i` in your `switchVal` if-statement block to `j` and `j+1`, respectfully;

---

By defining `j` with `i` in the declaration part of your for-loop, it seems as though you were associating `i` to `j` in an attempt to do an optimized Bubble Sort;  That is, you were attempting to avoid redundant comparisons.

you should instead use `i` in deriving the value to compare against `j` in the conditional part of the for-loop (i.e. the `max`):

`for (var j = 0; j < size - 1 - i; j++)`

With each complete `j` iteration loop occurrence, the element `emp[(size - 1 - i) - 1]` is going to be in it's correct, sorted index.  Any redundant comparisons would be skipped as it relates to that element.

Additionally, you should include a check on whether swaps have occurred in each complete `j` iteration loop to handle scenarios where a list is already sorted.

---

In this following code section, I've defined `Employee[] employees`. I'll demonstrate using `IOrderedEnumerable<T>.OrderBy<T, TKey>(Func<T, TKey>)` to initially sort - and assign the result to `employeesSortedByNameDesc`. I am then going to reverse that array and assign it to variable `reverseEmployees`; Finally, I'll use each `Employee[]` variable with the changed `Sort` method.

Overview and considerations:

- `Sort()` on the `employees`
- `Sort()` on the `employeesSortedByNameDesc`

  - no swapping should occur
  - minimum iterations
- `Sort()` on the `reversedEmployees`

  - each iteration of  `j` will have a `swap`
  - each **complete** `j` iteration will result in one item being sorted\shifted to the end of the array;
  - maximum iterations

---

#### `Employee` Type

```
public class Employee
{
    internal string FirstName { get; set; }
    internal string LastName { get; set; }

    public string GetName() => $"{FirstName} {LastName}".Trim();

}
```

#### `Sort()` method (with `hasSwapOccurred` check-conditional `break;`)

```
static void Sort(Employee[] emp, int size, int choice)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        bool hasSwapOccurred = false;

        for (int j = 0; j < size - 1 - i; j++)
        {
            bool switchval = false;
            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1: // ascending sort by employee name 
                    if (emp[j].GetName().CompareTo(emp[j + 1].GetName()) > 0)
                        switchval = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
                
            if (switchval)
            {
                Employee temp;
                temp = emp[j];
                emp[j] = emp[j + 1];
                emp[j + 1] = temp;
            }

            //Console.WriteLine($"(switchval := {switchval}, hasSwapOccurred := {hasSwapOccurred}) => [{string.Join(",", emp.Select(e => e.GetName()).ToArray()) }]");
        }
        //Console.WriteLine("-----");

        if (!hasSwapOccurred)
            break;
    }
    //Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

#### Program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var employees = new Employee[] 
    {
        new Employee { FirstName = "Bruce", LastName = "Wayne"},
        new Employee { FirstName = "Clark", LastName = "Kent"},
        new Employee { FirstName = "Ronald", LastName = "Raymond"},
        new Employee { FirstName = "Dinah", LastName = "Lance"},
        new Employee { FirstName = "Arthur", LastName = "Curry"},
        new Employee { FirstName = "Shayera", LastName = "Hol"}
    };

    var employeesSortedByNameDesc = employees.OrderBy(SelectEmployeeName).ToArray();

    var reversedEmployees = employeesSortedByNameDesc.Reverse().ToArray();

    Sort(employees, employees.Length, 1);
    Sort(employeesSortedByNameDesc, employeesSortedByNameDesc.Length, 1);
    Sort(reversedEmployees, reversedEmployees.Length, 1);

    string SelectEmployeeName(Employee e) => e.GetName();
}
```

#### `Console.Write` Output (it's commented out in sample code above)

[image: Screenshot of Sort Testing]